"I'd gone up through the doses." VS "I'd gone up the doses."
On TV, someone told about how she managed to lose weight by using a medicine, what she had gone trough, etc. At one point she said:

I'd gone up through the doses and reached my target on 10 milligrams. ITV - How to keep pounds off (see:2:40-2:44)

"go up through the doses" caught my attention. I know that "to go up" means "to increase", so it makes sense to me "I increased the doses", but what doesn't sit well with me is why we need the preposition "through".
For instance we say "I went up the stairs" (no need for "through"). So why in this case might she have said "I went up THROUGH the doses".

She could have chosen to say 'I went up the doses', but she didn't. Personal choice. Ordinary person on a TV show. No rule to apply here.

Perhaps she meant that she had gradually worked her way through a real or imaginary list of gradually increasing doses.

As Kate says, "through" indicates a movement "over the whole ... extent", passing through a series of doses, unlike "I increased the dose".

I suspect a reason for using "up through the does" rather than just "up the doses" is that "to up the dose" is a common phrase (phrasal verb?) which would refer to a single increase in dosage whereas the meaning is clearly (to me) that they went through stages to get to 10mg, as Kate suggests. "I went up the doses" would sound odd because it suggests two different meanings.

With medications it is often the case that the proper dose for the person must be discovered, and there is usually a protocol where the physician will start at a recommended dose and then make adjustments up or down as needed, taking into account both efficacy and undesirable side-effects.  To "go up through the doses" appears to refer to an established step-increase in dosage for a particular drug, a protocol followed when the target effect has not been attained.
